# cURL without cURL- problem

Tags: php, curl

I wanted to copy files from a remote server, but it seems that the remote host is using session, and needs cookies.

well I used this method
after defining variables...

```
$url="http://example.com/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=5255176&isnumber=5255174";
$nn = "\r\n";
$cookies="";
$request = GET . " " . str_replace ( " ", "%20", $url ) . " HTTP/1.1" . $nn . "Host: " . $host . $nn . "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.14) Gecko/20080404 Firefox/2.0.0.14" . $nn . "Accept: */*" . $nn . "Accept-Language: en-us;q=0.7,en;q=0.3" . $nn . "Accept-Charset: windows-1251,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7" . $nn . "Pragma: no-cache" . $nn . "Cache-Control: no-chache" . $nn  . $proxyauthorization . $referer . $cookies . "Connection: Close";

$fp= socksopen($Proxy,$port, $errno, $errstr, 15 );

socket_set_timeout ( $fp, 120 );

fputs ( $fp, $request );

fflush ( $fp );

//read header

$i = 1;

do {

$header.= @fgets ( $fp, 128 );

$i++;

} while ( strpos ( $header, $nn . $nn ) === false );

echo $header;

fclose ($fp);
```

now I have the header with cookies that the url said :

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily Content-length: 0 Content-type: text/html Server: Sun-ONE-Web-Server/6.1 Date: Mon, 28 Dec 2009 13:40:53 GMT Set-cookie: ERIGHTS=5YAaxxmNsMuTK87E1TCAohwDRuyqBaCgM-oehmg24bkzHplCtmgn7zMA==;path=/;domain=.example.org Set-cookie: WLSESSION=1528980108.20480.0000; expires=Tue, 29-Dec-2009 13:40:52 GMT; path=/ Location: http://example.com/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=5255176&isnumber=5255174"&tag=1 Via: 1.1 proxy-server1 Proxy-agent: Sun-Java-System-Web-Proxy-Server/4.
```

then I did some sting code and built this in the code:

```
$cookies="cookie: ERIGHTS=5YAaxxmNsMuTK87E1TCAohwDRuyqBaCgM-oehmg24bkzHplCtmgn7zMA==,WLSESSION=1528980108.20480.0000";
```

re-requesting the url with same method mentioned above
and again i have got **same header with another cookies**

It seams that the remote website is treating me as a first-time visitor each time and sets new cookies gain

there is one thing, the file i am trying to copy is a .pdf file exactly

i checked that by my browser, the results:

say the URL is:

`http://example.com/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=5344171&isnumber=5344169`

I checked the source code of the URL, it contains a redirection to another page that either is a javascript with iframe

source of the page (from my browser)

```
     <frameset rows="65,35%">
<frame src="http://example.com/stamp/banner.jsp" frameborder="0" framespacing="0" framepadding="0" scrolling="no" />
<frame src="http://example.com/stampPDF/getPDF.jsp?tp=&arnumber=5255176&isnumber=5255174" frameborder="0" />
```

as you see when I click the URL, it redirects me to URL2
the URL2 is this:`http://example.com/stampPDF/getPDF.jsp?tp=&arnumber=5255176&isnumber=5255174`

the URL2 contains .pdf file I can easily copy(download).

but when i use my code mentioned above, `$url="http://example.com/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=5255176&isnumber=5255174"`
it needs cookies to set with my request, when receive cookies and set and send cookies with my request it again replies a new cookie !!

what is wrong guys?

Comment: Why are you re-implementing an HTTP library?  Is there a problem with curl?  It has command line options for passing cookies, following redirects, etc...

Comment: cURL won't work properly with proxies, I tried 5 proxies, but only one of them worked out with cURL I don't khnow why, so I built my own code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you should check your cookie-composing logic. Name-value pairs in a cookie header are supposed to be separated with ';' not with ',': http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa920098.aspx#wce50concookieheadersanchor2.

 And (I'm sure you do this) I would double-check all the request headers with Fiddler, HttpAnalyzer or another similar tool.

Answer (score 0):

Are you passing over http://example.com/stampPDF/getPDF.jsp?tp=&arnumber=5255176&isnumber=5255174 as the referer?  The site may be checking that.

Comment: as you suggested, i included the referer ----> same result:(